# Upload and Download rate profiling in Android

Tags: android, networking, android-networking, speed-test

I'm trying to develop an Android app to measure the upload and download speed of my network, which probably I would need to run and profile it every 2 seconds or so. `SpeedTest.net` app is an ideal app working similarly, however, it is not open-source. Moreover, I would need it to be run every 2 seconds. It takes couple of seconds to finish test.

How can I do that? Currently I'm just downloading a small random .txt file found somewhere on Internet and measure `size/time-to-download` as a measure of download rate. But I get weird results every time. Apparently this approach is not working.

UPDATE: download is done. Any advices on how to implement the upload speeds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to download a considerably large file, something that takes atleast 15 seconds to download. The bigger the file, the better result you would receive. Use an always-on server with high availability. Also, use accumulation on the time of your network calls only (I believe that you must be using some socket to read in a `while` loop. So do `System.currentTimeMillis()` before and after `socket.read()` and keep adding them)

This is pretty much what `SpeedTest.net` does as well

As far as upload is concerned, you can do the same thing. A rough pseudo code :

```
upload (String remote, InputStream localfile){
     Socket s = openDataConnection(remote);
     OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream (s.getOutputStream(), MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

     byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
     long totalTime = 0L;
     while((buffer = localfile.read())!= -1){
         long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         os.write(buffer);
         long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         totalTime += (endTime - startTime);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To do the uploads, you will need to set up a two-way communication with the server. I would do it with a simple loop:

```
while(x){
Starttime =getCurrentTime()
Sendfile() //Send a Xmb file that the server can verify
waitForVerification() // Wait for a reply from server.
compareCurrentTimeWithStartingTime() // compare the times.
}
```