# Implementing Speed Test Android

Tags: android, speed-test

I have implemented speed test by downloading a specific file from the net and calculating it by dividing size of the file by the time taken to download. But the results do not match either with speedtest.net nor TRAI app. Even the results of speedtest obtained through SpeedTest.net app and of TRAI do not match. Please help about how should I check the speed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload and Download rate profiling in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536777/upload-and-download-rate-profiling-in-android)

Answer (score -2):

That depends on your server's capabilities, distance to the server, packets' route, etc. You can accurately measure only user's connection speed to the testing server. To any other server it can differ.

What I try to tell is that there is no way to accurately measure user's internet connection speed except testing connection speed to every server, the user connects to.